# Picturing complex projective curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

This is page 2 of the [notes](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/geordie/perverse_course/lectures.pdf).

I am confused how one obtains the "$\Bbb C$ picture" of curves of the form described

> $$ y^2=x(x-a)(x-b)$$
>   and its projectivization 
>   $$y^2 z= x(x-az)(x-bz)$$

The picture is in $\Bbb R^3$... and I'm confused in the purpose of projectivization.

More generally,

> how do people picture curves in $\Bbb P^2_{\Bbb C}$?

Comment: A "complex curve" is a 1-dimensional COMPLEX manifold/variety. Since the complex numbers are a 2-dimensional space over the real numbers, a 1-dimensional complex manifold is a 2-dimensional REAL manifold. I think the "$\Bbb{C}$-picture" is just the 2-dimensional real surface with the corresponding genus. On the top, the left picture is a genus 1 curve, and so the C-picture is a torus, which is a genus 1 surface.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to see how this follows from the formula. Can you perhaps spell out how one gets the torus from the formula? And what projectivization does to the picture?

Comment: Are you familiar with elliptic curves? (see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve). These equations are elliptic curves, which are always genus 1 curves. They can always be realized as a torus, since they are quotients of the complex plane by a lattice (this is explained on the wikipedia page)

Comment: An informal way of getting the torus from the formula is the following: assume for simplicity $a$ and $b$ are real, positive, $a<b$. Take two copies of the Riemman sphere $\mathbb C\cup\infty$, one for each choice of $\sqrt{}$ (the "positive" $\sqrt{}$ which maps to the right half-plane, and the "negative" which maps to the left half-plane). Cut them at $(\infty,0)$ and $(a,b)$, open the cuts slightly, and glue the two copies along the cut. Topologically this is a torus, i.e. Riemann surface of genus 1. Look up dessins d'enfants (and Riemann surfaces) for more.

Comment: Ran out of space: the cuts are at $[\infty,0]$ and $[a,b]$ because at any point on the cut the map $x\mapsto \sqrt{x(x-a)(x-b)}$ is not holomorphic. In order to make it holomorphic, we have to switch from "positive" $\sqrt{}$ to "negative" $\sqrt{}$ when traversing the cut. This requires a modification of the domain, obtained by gluing two cut copies of $\mathbb C\cup\infty$. Now when we traverse the cut, we move from one copy of the cut sphere to the other, i.e. we move from the "positive" $\sqrt{}$ to the "negative" $\sqrt{}$ (or vice-versa).

Comment: @BryanShih I know it's too late.. but I found this nice video in which she's actually drawing to show how the elliptic curve over the complex numbers turn to a torus!
- https://youtu.be/-D8KVhD4HlU?t=1130

Comment: This looks amazing (now years passed), thanks for the reference!